# Chrome Extension - Clear WebRequest only on new loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm trying to write an extension that stores all of the http header information in an array so that I can display it via popup.  In order to keep a tidy popup page, I'll need to clear the headers after each new load but I need a way of telling when that should occur.

1) Clear on new requestId

- doesn't work because requestId changes each time

2) Clear before webRequest after last onComplete occurred

- doesn't work because every image, main_frame, etc ends at onComplete therefore it clears after every image or page finishes

Any suggestions?  Here is what I have so far (option 2)... it kind of works if you're using only main_frame but that isn't ideal.

```
beforeRedirect = function( details )  {
    if (debug && details.tabId > 0 && typeof(tabs[details.tabId]) != 'undefined') {
        //returns all info stored in tabs array for the current tab
        log('The following data was recorded and stored', tabs[details.tabId]); 
    }
    //adds current tab to tabs array and stores header info in there
    var tabId = details.tabId;
    var url = details.url;
    details.type = 'normal';

    //if tab is null... init
    if (typeof(tabs[details.tabId]) == 'undefined') {
        tabs[tabId] = {};
        tabs[tabId].isRedirect = false;
    }

    //set Header info
    tabs[tabId].lasactive = new Date().getTime();
    if (typeof(details.redirectUrl) != 'undefined') {
        tabs[tabId].isRedirect = true;
        details.type = 'redirect';
    }

    if (typeof(tabs[tabId].requestId) == 'undefined' || tabs[tabId].completed) {
        tabs[tabId].requestId = details.requestId;
        log('clearing tab['+tabId+'] headers');
        tabs[tabId].requestHeader = []; //init or reset
    }
    tabs[tabId].requestHeader.push(details);

    log('Saved tab '+tabId+'\'s '+details.type+' header information', details);

    return;
}

completed = function( details )  {
    if (debug && details.tabId > 0 && typeof(tabs[details.tabId]) != 'undefined') {
        //returns all info stored in tabs array for the current tab
        log('The following data was recorded and stored', tabs[details.tabId]); 
    }
    //adds current tab to tabs array and stores header info in there
    var tabId = details.tabId;
    var url = details.url;
    details.type = 'normal';

    //if tab is null... init
    if (typeof(tabs[details.tabId]) == 'undefined') {
        tabs[tabId] = {};
        tabs[tabId].isRedirect = false;
    }

    //set Header info
    tabs[tabId].lasactive = new Date().getTime();
    if (typeof(details.redirectUrl) != 'undefined') {
        tabs[tabId].isRedirect = true;
        details.type = 'redirect';
    }

    if (typeof(tabs[tabId].requestId) == 'undefined' || tabs[tabId].completed) {
        log('clearing tab['+tabId+'] headers');
        tabs[tabId].requestId = details.requestId;
        tabs[tabId].requestHeader = []; //init or reset
    }
    tabs[tabId].requestHeader.push(details);
    tabs[tabId].completed = true;
    log('Saved tab '+tabId+'\'s '+details.type+' header information', details);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe exactly what is not working or what else you need here?

Comment: When I run tabs[48] from the chrome console, I expect an array of header information for the tab with tab.id=48.  If I'm loading a page that has one image and my filter is {'urls':['<all_urls>', 'types':['main_frame', 'image']}, I expect two elements in my headers array.  tabs[48].requestHeaders[1] would be the image and tabs[48].requestHeaders[0] would be the page.  What's happening is the page seems to be loading first.  Once that completes, the image comes next.  Since main_frame finished as 'onComplete', Once I start storing the header info for the 'image', the 'main_frame' gets cleared.

Comment: I need a way of clearing headers that I've stored but only at the start of a new page load/refresh.  Is that even possible?

Comment: Thought about comparing the URL but a 302 would switch the URL so that wouldn't work.  Maybe a combination of URL & requestId to set the "clear" flag for next request?